# Effect of Schengen visa refusal on residence renewal in the UK?

Tags: uk, visa-refusals

I have a UK resident visa that expires in October this year. I applied for a Schengen visa for France (with a return flight to the UK via Dusseldorf). In the past, I already had 2 Schengen visas and I have visited Amsterdam before.

My visa was refused based on me not justifying the purpose of visit, my finances and medical insurance. I have a mortgage, bank cards and an emergency credit card for emergency funds, but this was not added to my application by my agent.

Will this affect my residence renewal in the UK?

Comment: Hi Cynthia. I have edited your question to adapt it to the expected question style on this page. Feel free to edit the edits in case anything is incorrect now. Note that your question may be more well-suited for expatriates.stackexchange.com

Comment: @Cynthia For clarity, what is your nationality and what were the proposed travel dates to France? Will the basis of your residence status in the U.K. change eg do you have an expiring employment contract?

Comment: Using an agent seems to be a great way to get a visa refusal. In general you should apply for visitor visas yourself.

Answer (score 2):

The shortcomings that resulted in your failed Schengen visa application are not the same as the factors considered for residence in the UK.

As you note, your travel plans were questioned, and you, or your agent, didn't offer proof of available funds or medical insurance coverage.

The long-term right to remain in the UK is based on far greater criteria than those for a short-term visit to a country. The recent Schengen visa refusal is unlikely to impact a request to extend leave to remain in the UK.